# IE7 Pro Plug-in w/ IE9: Where's my IE7 Pro options icon? Used to be in the status bar

Tags: icons, internet-explorer-9

Back when I had IE7 and IE8, the IE7 Pro options icon would show on the right side of my browser's status bar.  This icon would expose additional options not available by the regular menu, options such as saving the current web page to an image, for example.

After upgrading to IE9, though, it appears to have disappeared.  Does anyone know what could have happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to use IE7Pro as well.

IE7Pro stopped development before IE8 final released (last update was in 2010, and they were just starting work on 'IE8 Beta' compatibility) and has no support for IE9.

Check out [this thread](http://forum.ie7pro.com/viewtopic.php?id=4628) on their forums (from 2009):

> 14-05-2009 13:23:35 - I remember there were some posts about the IE7Pro team working with Intel. What happened to that? Was the project canceled and as a result IEPro for IE8 was canceled too?
>
> 15-05-2009 21:56:02 - No onw knows. All we are guessing that IE7Pro develpers has canceled further develop. From them no words no voice no info.

The good news is, there are alternatives for many/all of it's features available for IE9, you just have to find ones you need and like.

Comment: It appears you're right about discontinued development.  That is a real shame.  I emailed them begging for them to continue development in the hopes I am one of hundreds of other users who can't live without IE7 Pro.  I guess I'll be searching for a replacement.  It will probably require several other add-ins to equal the functionality of IE7 Pro.

Answer (score 2):

No, but IE7Pro works with IE9.  So far, the only 'issue' I have run into is the lack of the IE7Pro icon in the status bar.  Fortunately, Ctl + ~ brings up the context menu that you'd normally see by clicking on the (missing in IE9) IE7Pro icon in the status bar.  You can also hit Ctl + F7 to bring up the settings.  HTH

Comment: I just installed IE7Pro and CTRL+~ is not working for me.